# Is there a missing definition for addition of vector fields?

Tags: differential-geometry, modules, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, smooth-functions

In proving $\mathfrak X(U)$ is a $C^{\infty}U$-module, for an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$  my book defines scalar multiplication of smooth vector fields $U$ by smooth functions on $U$ as

$$[fX]_p := f(p)X_p$$

[image]

I could not find a definition for addition. Is it $[X+Y]_p  := X_p + Y_p$ ? Otherwise, with what definition do we prove the "Abelian group" part of showing $\mathfrak X(U)$ is a $C^{\infty}U$-module?

My book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu.

Comment: It is pointwise addition, just as you say.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Charlie pointed in the comments, it is just your regular pointwise addition:
$$(X+Y)_p=X_p+Y_p$$